# Excel automatically update one field from another and vice versa

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with a list of costs, prices and margins. What I would like to do is if a user wants to change the margin, the price would update, and if they want to change the price, the margin would update.

I have searched but so far I have not being able to find a good answer. Could you guys help me out here? Thank's!

EDIT: Does anyone know how to do this with VBA?

Comment: You need to add additionnal columns, because writing in a cell replaces the formula if there is one. You will not be able to do it off 3 values only. You'd need a set of values for changing the price, and a double for changing the margin. If you can't to that you'll have to use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Initially you would need to define a relationship between cost,price & margin.

For example:- If Price-Cost=Margin & Price is mentioned in A1, Cost in B1, Margin in C1.

So Cost would be fixed whereas Price & Margin would change. So in C1 delete the content and write formula in cell as =A1-B1. So in this case if you change either Price or Cost Margin will change.

Similarly in Price i.e. A1 delete the content and write formula in cell as =B1+C1. So if cost or margin is changed Price also changes.

Note: Both cannot be used, Use either one of these.

Comment: Yeah, what i wanted was to do using either of them, not just one, seems that the only way to do it is VBA.

Comment: I am not sure if VBA will allow you the same. As it's circular dependency.